# CSS Selector not finding ID

Tags: css

I am trying to select the glyphicon and make it centered. What would be the correct selector to style the glyphicon inside the span element?

```
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class = "row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class = "well">
                    <h1</h1>
                </div>
             <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg page-scroll" href="#employment" id="arrow"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>


#arrow {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: If you add `color: #f00;` I'll bet you it *is* finding the element. But `text-align: center` will only work on `block`, or `inline-block` (or `float`-ed) elements with a width, not `<a>` elements (unless you specify one of those `display`, or `float`, properties)

Comment: `text-align` affects inline elements inside of the element the rule lives on, but `<a>` itself is inline and is not going to be centered in its parent block element. Try putting the CSS rule on the parent `<div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add text-align:center to the parent of the link/glyphicon:

```
.row .col-md-12 {
      text-align:center;
}
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/LbWNZMuLom)**

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to manipulate only the  tag with the Glyphicon in it, simply give the  tag an ID and select it that way.

```
<span id="myStyledGlyph" class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
```

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Alignment will be difficult on the Glyphicon directly, since it is in an  tag and already within a

You could trying wrapping the entire  tag in a  tag and assign an id to that  like this:

```
<div id="alignThisDiv"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg page-scroll" href="#employment" id="arrow"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a></div>
```

Comment: yes by putting a parent div I was able to style it by .arrow .row .col-md-12 thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it! If my response was helpful to you, consider marking it as the answer to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cause `id` is unique you can use `id` selector as you did. Check DOM to see if there are more than one elements with `id` `#arrow` and if there are then change them. Cause `id` should be UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you also need `vertical-align: middle`:

```
#arrow {
    text-align: center;
}
#arrow > .glyphicon {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `span` contains text and you want to align it as center then `text-align: center` will work. As far as, I am getting from your question, the `span` having class `glyphicon` would have some image/icon as its background and you want to align the `span` as center.

Try following and see if this helps you -

```
#arrow .glyphicon{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```